# ASP.NET MVC3 project, ajax callback works with " contentType: 'text/json; charset=utf-8' " but " contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' "

Tags: c#, json, header, content-type

Recently, I convert my company's mvc2 site to mvc3. Most features went well but ajax call failed. the js code locates on aspx page(it was mvc 2)
Original code:

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
        url: '<%= Url.Action("MethodName", "Home") %>',
        data: JSON.stringify(results), //results is some data with json format
        traditional: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: otherJSFunction
    })
```

When I ran the code, I got an error from C# as following. 
" System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName) "

I tried to add attribute [DataContract] to Model class but no use. When I tried to change the original code's "application" to "text", it works. Code as following:

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
        url: '<%= Url.Action("MethodName", "Home") %>',
        data: JSON.stringify(results), ////results is some data with json format
        traditional: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'text/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: otherJSFunction
    })
```

I checked a lot of tickets from stackoverflow and documents, people always say "application/json" is the right way. But the right way doesn't work on my case. Is there anyone can help me to explain why this happened?

Thank you.

Comment: mmm, some starters for 10.
I don't think you need the " traditional: true," flag and the " JSON.stringify" or the contentType.

Never had the need for any of them in my projects, What jquery are you on - should be on around 3.x

Comment: @RichardHousham, the jQuery version is 1.5. The project was created by someone else, and team lead doesn't want me to make too much change on the current working code. I have to keep the ajax settings.

Comment: Mmm, well a whole lot of stuff now relies on jquery version 1.8 including the unobtrusive validation which is kinda part of the MVC3 framework.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/#show-github-usage
I would also say that by using such an old version that's got quite a few vulnerabilities so an upgrade would be a good idea. Still, though I would stick to by previous advice see if that helps.. What is the exception?

Comment: thanks @RichardHousham, I have tried to upgrade the jquery to 1.8. The issue was still there. I agree with you that this issue was because of the old version issue. I just want to know why this happened. I checked the developer tool, the request data are the exact same between "application/json" and "text/json"

Comment: So what's the actual exception back from the controller?
Check the json submitted is valid as well.